# Reverse the display of a date using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, date

I have a date returned in this format YYYY-MM-DD, e.g. 2011-04-29.  Using jQuery how can I make the date 29-04-2011?

Comment: You don't use jQuery for things like that. However, JavaScript string functions such as `split()` are your friend. If you want something better, use `Date.js`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [.reverse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)

```
var pieces = '2011-07-27'.split('-');
pieces.reverse();
var reversed = pieces.join('-');
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, I am getting the created time from a album on Facebook. FYI Facebook displays the created time as 2011-09-21T14:35:51+0000.  I used the following to code to get the date,  var date = 2011-09-21T14:35:51+0000;
var removeTime = date.split('T')[0];
var pieces = removeTime.split('-');
pieces.reverse();
var reversed = pieces.join('-'); alert(reversed);

Comment: You can also do it on 1 line :
date.split('-').reverse().join('-')

Answer (score 2):

```
var parts = '2011-07-27'.split(/-/);
parts.reverse();
alert(parts.join('-'));
```