# How to get value dd/mm/yyyy to mm/dd/yyyy in eonasdan bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I want to get value input(text) tag : dd/mm/yyyy and convert this value is : mm/dd/yyyy and send server.

Comment: Please provide some example code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse the display of a date using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538255/reverse-the-display-of-a-date-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the selected date using [`date`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#date) method and then convert format using moment [`format`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) function to convert Date in the format you need.
I suggest to edit your question and add some code to have more accurate answer, anyway the following example can help you to get the job done:

```js
$(function () {
  // Init Eonasdan datetimepicker
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({format: 'DD-MM-YYYY'});
  $('#btnSend').click(function(){
    // Get selected date (moment object)
    var myDate = $('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").date();
    if( myDate != null ){
      // Convert moment date to string chosing format
      var dateStringForServer = myDate.format('MM-DD-YYYY');
      alert('send: '+dateStringForServer);
    }
    
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
  <input type='text' class="form-control" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
</div>
<button id="btnSend" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
```